# create line styled button in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am currently working on creating a `line styled button` show in the picture below.

[image]

I have no idea on how to `create a lined button` as i am new to android programming.

Please help?

Thank you

Comment: What did you try so far? Please don't expect free code or research!

Comment: a simple shape with a stroke as xml layout will do the trick....

Answer (score 2):

Check following code it will help you

rounded_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#3c993c"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>


</shape>
```

In Activity Xml

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use [shape drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

`shape.xml` in drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#1a1a1a" />
</shape>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

*for more detail see [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html) tutorials for android*

Answer (score 1):

in Android all layout is set by xml file, you can define the shape and the color of your button just using an xml file.

First of all, you have to create a file called buttonshape.xml in the drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners android:radius="8dp"/>
<solid android:color="#FFF"/>
<size 
    android:width="275dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#19a865"/>
</shape>
```

Then, you have to say at the button you want to use this xml as background.

```
<Button
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:textColor="#19a865"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"/>
```

Output:

[image: refresh button]

That's all!